# how to display data that is related to a specific cell in excel 2010?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created 2 columns, the first has a category of a system using data validation, and the second has the description and failures of that system.
The purpose of that is to open a malfunction on some parts.
In a different sheet I wish to do the same only this time I want to choose the system and the description will automatically appear in the next column showing me all the malfunctions I have written on this system.
I am not very good at all the functions of excel. but I still searched for one that might help me. I have tried using the DGET function but it got me nowhere.

[image: example]

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you want on the second spreadsheet. A simple 3-row example could help!

Comment: In the second spreadsheet I want to be able to select a system for example Engine and it will show me every description i have written on that system

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the solution here - it's a bit tricky to explain without copy-pasting the whole thing:
https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values

Also take a look at vlookup() if you're working across spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

As expected, all of the responses you've seen ehere - and probably elsewhere - are ponyers to VLookup, or a refusal to answer your question.

I'm guessing that you're using DGET() because you need to retrieve data from one named column, using a match for a search term in another named column; and you're that because you can't rely on column ordinals or addresses - you *have* to do it by name.

VLookup won't do that for you: not without extremely complex and fragile array formulae.

The bad news is: **Microsoft NEVER published a working example of a DGET() formula or any corresponding VBA Worksheet Function code.**

There's page after page  of descriptive text and general explanation in the helpfiles and on MSDN: but no working example. Nobody in Redmond ever sat down and made the DGET() function work with a reproducible set of function parameters and published a screen-shot the working formula.

I'll let you guess why that is.

Maybe there's an example somewhere that is, in effect, a VLookup implemented for known column ordinals using DGET(). If there is, I never found it and you won't either: and it would, of course, be useless for any application where you're working with field names instead of known ordinals.

What you need to do is capture the tabulated data range, with field names in the top row, and pass it to a SQL query using ADODB or MS-Query. That bad new for *that* is that all the MS-JET Excel drivers have a fatal memory leak.

After that fails, you're left exporting the data somewhere that a proper database app can run the SQL: and that's actually the right thing to do, because your attempt at using DGET() is a relational data query.

If you're left with the need to do this entirely in Excel, you have reached a level of desperation normally associated with the last survivor of an airplane crash who, having devoured the charred remains of his unlucky fellow passengers, is finally forced to contemplate the awful exigency of opening and eating the inflight catering meals.

The grisly details for the equivalent in Excel are [a Horrible Hack](http://excellerando.blogspot.com/2014/09/from-time-to-time-it-necessary-to.html) published here:

http://excellerando.blogspot.com/2014/09/from-time-to-time-it-necessary-to.html